# Start new instance on Visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, macros

In my VS2010, I have a "Solution" which contains 2 projects.
Test (my default project) and "Db" (a dll called/used by Test)

I've mapped CTRL-F5 on "Start new instance" for debug purpose.

If my active document (.cpp) belongs to Test, everything is ok, the debugger runs normally.

But if my focused document belongs to the "Db" project, I get the following message : "Unable to start db.dll"

So I have to right click on my "Test" project a select in the context menu "Start new instance"
:(

In fact I would like to have the same behavior than the old VC6 :)

Any idea of to do this with the keyboard ? (a macro in guess)

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is already available in the default VS keyboard mapping.  If necessary, right-click your Test project and select "Set as Startup Project".  Which makes it displayed in bold type.  Pressing F5 now always starts your Test project, regardless what is active in the IDE.  Similarly, the default keyboard mapping for Ctrl+F5 always starts this project without the debugger.